# Ruby on Rails - ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a project in Ruby on rails 5.2, and in this route it tells me that I have an error and that the specified route is not found. but when checking, the route is there or at least I think so.

Here's my routes.rb:

```
resources :checkin do
   post :get_barcode, on: :collection
end
```

checkin_controller.rb:

```
class CheckinController < ApplicationController
def index
    @checkin = CheckIn.all
end

def show
end

def new
    @checkin = CheckIn.new
    @checkin.upc = params[:upc]
end

def edit
end

def update
end

def destroy
end

def get_barcode
    @checkin = Merchant.find_or_initialize_by(upc: params[:upc])
    unless @checkin.new_record?
        redirect_to @checkin
    else
        redirect_to new_product_path(upc: params[:upc])
    end
end
end
```

And my link in my view:

```
<%= link_to "Check-In", checkin_path, :class => "nav-link" %>
```

here's a image of my error page:
[image]

Comment: Which of the defined routes are you expecting `checkin_path` to match?

Comment: @matthewd I wait for the route that leads me to index. Show me in that view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `rake routes` in your console, you'll see that your routes are:

```
get_barcode_checkin_index POST   /checkin/get_barcode(.:format)                       checkin#get_barcode
            checkin_index GET    /checkin(.:format)                                   checkin#index
                          POST   /checkin(.:format)                                   checkin#create
              new_checkin GET    /checkin/new(.:format)                               checkin#new
             edit_checkin GET    /checkin/:id/edit(.:format)                          checkin#edit
                  checkin GET    /checkin/:id(.:format)                               checkin#show
                          PATCH  /checkin/:id(.:format)                               checkin#update
                          PUT    /checkin/:id(.:format)                               checkin#update
                          DELETE /checkin/:id(.:format)                               checkin#destroy
```

As you can see, the `checkin_path` expects an `id`, which you are not providing here:

```
<%= link_to "Check-In", checkin_path, :class => "nav-link" %>
```

Your error probably says something about missing id, but you don't provide the error in your question, so we can't see exactly what it says.

BTW, by convention, `CheckinController` should probably be `CheckinsController`. And your routes should probably be:

```
resources :checkins do
   post :get_barcode, on: :collection
end
```

Comment: images. yuck. Anyway, you are in fact missing the `:id` as indicated by `missing_required_keys: [:id]`.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in one of your comments, you're expecting the URL for the index page? 
 Then instead of

```
<%= link_to "Check-In", checkin_path, :class => "nav-link" %>`
```

you need to use

```
<%= link_to "Check-In", checkin_index_path, :class => "nav-link" %>
```